# Entity outside of ASP.NET-Identity framework not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I'm playing around with ASP.NET 5 Identity and getting stuck.

This is boilerplate context created by Identity:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

I've added an additional entity `Transactions` that exists outside of the Identity framework.

When I launch the site, all the authentication stuff works fine, but when I try to query `Transactions` I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: No database providers are configured.
>   Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring in your
>   DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up
>   services.

Looking further into this error, all signs seem to point to register the service in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Despite this, still getting the error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was something stupid, found an answer.

When using the ef context, when it's newly derived, the context is not set.

So it needs to be injected:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _appCtx;

    public HomeController(
        ApplicationDbContext appCtx)
    {
        _appCtx = appCtx;
    }

    public JsonResult Durr()
    {
        return new JsonResult(_appCtx.Users.ToList());    
    }
}
```